# Material UI select not showing label

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm having a heck of a time with Material UI's "Select" - about 10 hours into trying to get one working the way I'd like.  I'd really appreciate some help.

This question is related to a previous one: [Select MenuItem doesn't show when JSX saved to state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51032791/select-menuitem-doesnt-show-when-jsx-saved-to-state) and I suspect that if the "why" were answered on that, I might get a better idea of what's going on.

What I'm trying to accomplish is having a Select that does the following normal things:

- has all the UI goodies (shows the question in the select spot, then
  moves the question smaller and out of the way after you select a
  non-null selection)
- upon selecting something, the label shows up (as one would expect in
  a drop down) rather than a blank (as I have been experiencing - check
  previous question)
- no warnings in the console about 'value' being undefined
- when I click away from the select after selecting something, I don't
  want the question label to move back on top of the answer like this:
  [image: selected option and question label on top of each other]
- I want a 'none' option that returns the select back to it's "empty"
  form (That is to say, the question label shows at normal size in the
  select)
- I can set a selection to be selected by default

These shouldn't be hard tasks, but I can't for the life of me get it. It' rather embarrassing.

- Then, upon selecting something, I want to save that selection (along
  with the other selection options) to state (so I can save it to
  localStorage so the larger form doesn't 'reset' upon page refresh)

Either way, I've currently got this JSX - effectively a cut-and-paste from the material ui demos with a map for the `MenuItems`:

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
<InputLabel htmlFor={this.props.label}>{this.props.label}</InputLabel>
<Select
    value={this.state.selectLabel}
    onChange={this.handleSelectChange}
    inputProps={{
        name: 'selectLabel',  
        id: this.props.label,
    }}
>
{this.props.value.map(valueLabelPair =>
                <MenuItem
                    key={this.props.XMLvalue + "_" + valueLabelPair.label}
                    value={valueLabelPair.value}
                >
                    {valueLabelPair.label}
                </MenuItem>
            )}
</Select>
</FormControl>
```

the handleSelectChange looks like this -- again, exactly the same as the material UI demo.

```
handleSelectChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
};
```

This kind of works except the console gives me the following error:

> Failed prop type: The prop `value` is marked as required in
>   `SelectInput`, but its value is `undefined`.

and the selected option and question label go on top of each other after you click away, like so: [image: selected option and question label on top of each other]

Further, if I try to add in this code (in the componentDidMount function) with the goal of being able to pass in the 'selected'/default option...

```
componentDidMount() {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.props.value.length; i++) {
        if(this.props.value[i].selected) {
            // *works* console.log("selected found: " + this.props.value[i].label);
            this.setState({selectLabel:this.props.value[i].label});
        }
    }
}
```

it does not update the give me a default answer and also gives me the following additional error in the console (in addition to all issues above):

> Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type hidden
>   to be controlled. Input elements should not switch from uncontrolled
>   to controlled (or vice versa). Decide between using a controlled or
>   uncontrolled input element for the lifetime of the component.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

Just define **selectLabel** into constructor:

```
constructor () {
    super()
    this.state = {
        selectLabel:'',
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure as to why the above solution did not work.

However, I rebuilt the Select to return "option" elements instead of "MenuItem" elements with the following function:

```
buildSelectOptions(optionsPairs) {  // note, this references props and blank option could be split out for reuse
    var JSX_return = [];

    if (this.props.includeBlank && this.props.includeBlank === true) {
        JSX_return.push(<option key="nada" value="" />);
    }

    for (var optionLabel in optionsPairs) {
        JSX_return.push(<option key={optionLabel} value={optionsPairs[optionLabel]}>{optionLabel}</option>);
    }
    return JSX_return;
}
```

My render now looks like this:

```
<FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
    <InputLabel htmlFor="age-native-simple">{this.props.label}</InputLabel>
    <Select
        native
        value={this.state.value}
        onChange={this.handleSelectChange('value')}
        inputProps={{
            name: this.props.label,
            id: this.props.id,
          }}
    >
        {this.buildSelectOptions(this.props.options)}

    </Select>
    <FormHelperText>{this.props.helperText}</FormHelperText>
</FormControl>
```

And the event handler looks like this:

```
handleSelectChange = name => event => {  //FUTURE: combine the handlers  (or split out question types to sub-components)
    this.setState({ [name]: event.target.value },
        () => this.props.stateChangeHandler(this)
    );
};
```

the props passed to this object look like this:

```
{
    "key": "test4",
    "id": "test4",
    "label": "Question Label 4",
    "XMLValue": "XMLQ4",
    "type": "DropDown",
    "includeBlank": true,
    "helperText": "PCodes FTW!",
    "options": {
        "No oe": "NA",
        "My1": "One",
        "My2": "Two",
        "My3": "three"
    },
    "value": "One"
}
```

One of the key concepts for me was to learn that the `value` field on the `Select` element should be pointed at an item in `this.state`.  Then, the onChange needs to pass the name of that state variable (which, confusingly, I have named 'value') to the eventHandler function.

The double arrow function header (curried function) of the `handleSelectChange` function still confuses me... (I don't understand how the 'event' property is getting there, given I'm calling this function with a single parameter)... but this works for now and I can try to refactor into syntax I am comfortable with (ie: `function(a, b) { *do something* }` ) at some future date. (yeah....)

Answer (score 0):

Add class `radio_label` :

```
<FormControlLabel value="male" label="Male" control={<Radio />}  className="radio_label"/>
```

Add css property :

```
.radio_label{
    color:black
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.